# Bootstrap table's styles messed up when used with Ember.js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, html-table

I work with bootstrap. When I create a table in plain HTML, bootstrap's table styles are applied as expected.

But, when I insert the *same* HTML into an Ember.js template, the bootstrap's table styles don't seem to apply (e.g. table borders, paddings and stripes are not present). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5evymbou/

**Plain HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="search-results" class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                    <td>c</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The same HTML - but used in an Ember template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="search-results" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script>
    App = Em.Application.create({
        rootElement: '#root'
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the Bootsrap CSS relies on the presence of `tbody`,`thead` etc. which are automatically inserted in to your HTML by the browser if you don't include them. You can check this yourself by inspecting your `table` in your browsers development tools.

Because your ember table is added to the DOM after the HTML is parsed, these element are not automatically created by the browser.

**Example of Bootstrap CSS:**

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**You can fix your code easily by adding a `tbody` element to your template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="search-results" class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>b</td>
                            <td>c</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>b</td>
                            <td>c</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5evymbou/1/)

Comment: Thanks for answer - that solves it. (Lol, after I posted the question, I actually browsed the bootstrap's styles and figured it out too - serendipity :).